# grep records on multiple criteria

Tags: r, criteria

I have a series of vendors and billing amounts, with billing amounts grouped into buckets.

I want to subset the dataset to only providers who have amounts in both ‘< 100’ buckets, as well as ’500-1000’ buckets or ‘> 1000’ buckets. Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(GrossAmt = c(74.37, 69.69, 705.76, 694.12, 5243, 
2680.95, 23270, 64.31, 64.31, 64.31, 1863.6, 4030.38, 43.86, 
36.57, 37.29, 31.02, 59.43, 27.65), VenName = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("Labcorp", "Quest Diagnostics Incorporated", 
"THOMAS JEFFERSON UNIV HOSPITAL", "WASHINGTON HOSPITAL CENTER"
), class = "factor"), AmtGrp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("<= 100", 
"> 1000", "500 - 1000"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("GrossAmt", 
"VenName", "AmtGrp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

In my example, the resulting dataset would have all records from TJU Hospital & Washington Hospital Center, since they have bills both < $100 & in one of the higher buckets. The other providers would be filtered out b/c they don't have bills > $500.

I would provide the work that I've done so far, but honestly not sure where to begin on this one so forgive me. My first instinct is that I need to set up a grep command for records based on the grouping criteria, but i don't know how to match based on the vendor's name.

**Edit - Expanded Question:**

How can I filter by any Vendor where they fall into more than one amt group, irrespective of what the specific amount group is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

chain(df, group_by(VenName), 
          filter(any(AmtGrp == '<= 100'),
                 !all(AmtGrp == '<= 100')))
```

Edit: second question

```
chain(df, group_by(VenName), 
          filter(length(unique(AmtGrp)) > 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with the base functions `ave` and `subset`:

```
subset(df, as.logical(ave(as.character(AmtGrp), VenName, FUN = function(x) 
  any(x == "<= 100") & any(x %in% c("500 - 1000", "> 1000")))))

   GrossAmt                        VenName     AmtGrp
1     74.37 THOMAS JEFFERSON UNIV HOSPITAL     <= 100
2     69.69 THOMAS JEFFERSON UNIV HOSPITAL     <= 100
3    705.76 THOMAS JEFFERSON UNIV HOSPITAL 500 - 1000
4    694.12 THOMAS JEFFERSON UNIV HOSPITAL 500 - 1000
5   5243.00 THOMAS JEFFERSON UNIV HOSPITAL     > 1000
6   2680.95 THOMAS JEFFERSON UNIV HOSPITAL     > 1000
7  23270.00 THOMAS JEFFERSON UNIV HOSPITAL     > 1000
8     64.31     WASHINGTON HOSPITAL CENTER     <= 100
9     64.31     WASHINGTON HOSPITAL CENTER     <= 100
10    64.31     WASHINGTON HOSPITAL CENTER     <= 100
11  1863.60     WASHINGTON HOSPITAL CENTER     > 1000
12  4030.38     WASHINGTON HOSPITAL CENTER     > 1000
```